# htaccess reg ex to add trailing slash to directories but not some drupal aliases

Tags: regex, .htaccess, drupal, mod-rewrite

I'm very new to reg ex's and have a number of drupal aliases including some legacy .html files (aliases) that I want to retain for SEO reasons. I need to force slashes on virtual directories and force no slashes on .html aliases.

So far I have this code which adds the slashes to directories and not to .html but it still allows a user or agent to go to .html/ - any help rewriting the removal or 404 of this slash greatly appreciated.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#is not an htm/l file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html?$ [NC]
#does not end with a slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What's the problem here? Are those rules adding a trailing slash when there's a URL ending in `.html`? Or do you want to prevent people from actually adding trailing slashes to requests for an html file?

Comment: The rule is working as it's supposed to but we want to add something to prevent people, and more importantly spiders, from adding the trailing slash to requests for an html file. As I understand it, this would normally result in a 404 error by default but for some reason when the .html file is an alias in drupal it still shows the page when a trailing slash is added. news.html is the same as news.html/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this right below the `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.html?)/$ /$1$2 [R=301,L]
```